# Django Celery Persistent revoke

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

So I have a project in Django that uses Celery and sometimes I am revoking tasks.

Celery has the ability to persist revokes even if the worker is restarted (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#worker-persistent-revokes)

However when following the docs I get this error:

```
anydbm.error: db type could not be determined
```

I have tried copying the code from the docs and pointing it to my own db I made using:

```
sqlite3 worker.db
```

But I can't seem to work it out...

I'd love some help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I worked it out in the end.

By adding this to settings.py it started working:

```
CELERYD_STATE_DB = "celery_state.db"
```